# Ruby Array Attributes

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am trying to access the Shopify API using the shopify-api gem. In particular, I am trying to access the price of an item, which is contained in an array.

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(id)
variant = product.variants
```

`variant` here is an array, and when I do `puts variant.inspect`, I get

```
[
  #<ShopifyAPI::Variant:0x000000041c9e50 @attributes={
    "id"=>23923477191,
    "title"=>"Default Title",
    "price"=>"6.00",
    "sku"=>"shirts",
    "position"=>1,
    "grams"=>0,
    "inventory_policy"=>"deny",
    "compare_at_price"=>nil,
    "fulfillment_service"=>"manual",
    "inventory_management"=>"shopify",
    "option1"=>"Default Title",
    "option2"=>nil,
    "option3"=>nil,
    "created_at"=>"2016-06-30T14:06:07-04:00",
    "updated_at"=>"2016-07-16T19:00:07-04:00",
    "taxable"=>true,
    "barcode"=>"",
    "image_id"=>nil,
    "inventory_quantity"=>1,
    "weight"=>0.0,
    "weight_unit"=>"kg",
    "old_inventory_quantity"=>1,
    "requires_shipping"=>true
  }, @prefix_options={:product_id=>7509869767}, @persisted=true>
]
```

How do I access/change 'price' under '@attributes`?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are what Ruby calls object properties. Just access it as you would a property in most other languages.

Get the item of the array you want (0 in this example) and then access the price attribute

`variant[0].price`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`variant.first["price"]`

The `variant` array has 3 elements; the @attributes element is the first.
This `@attributes` element is a hash map, and you are looking for the value at key `"price"`.